# Is there a python package that supports Min-Max and Sum scaling of a data sample?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been looking for a python package/command that is able to scale a given data sample with a predefined min, max and total sum for the to-be scaled sample. I've attempted to use the MinMaxScaler() function of the sklearn.preprocessing package as in the example underneath.

Given a base sample:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd

base_sample = pd.DataFrame([5 , 20 , 30 , 35, 45 , 60])

sample_min = 10
sample_max = 50

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (sample_min , sample_max))
        
scaled_sample = scaler.fit_transform(base_sample)

print(scaled_sample)
```

Producing:

```
[[10.        ]
 [20.90909091]
 [28.18181818]
 [31.81818182]
 [39.09090909]
 [50.        ]]
```

With Sum:

```
print(scaled_sample.sum())
180.0
```

Yet what I need is a command that is able to do the above yet with a predefined different sum, for example based on the sum of the original sample:

```
print(base_sample.sum())
195
```

or any other predefined sum. In essence the values inbetween the min and max have to be scaled accordingly to match the sum without violating the min and max constraints. I've been doing this kind of exercise for a long time within a commercial tool that unfortunately does not allow me to have a look under the hood for the underlying formulation. Any suggestions on how to proceed would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a linear transformation, this is not possible. You cannot transform the values of a vector to an arbitrary minimum, maximum and sum. You can achieve this with non-linear transforms, given that you can scale certain weights more up/down than others to control the extrema while adjusting the sum (or vice versa). This would become an optimization problem, which has an infinite amount of answers as you can literally do anything with the transformed vector. You can limit this by setting the transformation function.

Comment: You're absolutely right that the scaling i'm envisioning is non-linear. Do you have any suggestions on a python package that can assist with this? Note that i'm working with large datasets so efficiency is also a factor.

Comment: I don't think this exists for a general case. I think it is easiest to come up with something yourself. 
Note that your sum is highly constraint, `for n samples: min * (n-1) + max < sum < max * (n - 1) + min`.
You can do something like shifting datapoints towards the minimum or maximum to de-/increase the sum, scale the scalars in between the extrema with any sort of function. Finding the right constants for such scaling function would probably be easiest to solve with a general solver like scipy.optimize, pulp, cvxpy, etc.

Comment: Thanks Niels, i'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works,

```
scaled_sample/scaler.scale_
```

The `scaler.scale_` is equivalent to `(max - min) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))`

Comment: Can you provide an example in code on how this would work given the above described constraints - i.e. scaling the min, max and sum?